# Generate all dependencies of a model with swagger-codegen

Tags: swift, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am generating Swift model objects using `swagger-codegen`, like so:

```
swagger-codegen generate -i swagger.json -l swift5 -o . -Dmodels=MyModel
```

This seems to correctly generate a file for `MyModel` as well as files for each of the models on which `MyModel` depends. However, it doesn't generate model dependencies at a deeper level, so the resulting code will not compile because types are missing.

I can't find anything in the documentation or elsewhere about this. And as far as I understand the tool, it is probably not specific to Swift generation.

Is there a way to get it to recursively pull in all the models that are required for the model I want to generate? I don't wish to just include all models.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to generate everything to start with and then remove those files that you don't need. This may work better in your use case.